# SqlException was unhandled(incorrect syntax error)

Tags: syntax, throw, unhandled-exception, catch-block

When I try to enter login, the program is sending me throw section & writing something about incorrect synxtax error '='.

[image: Error image]

```
public bool personelEntryControl(string password, int UserId)
{
    bool result = false;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(gnl.conString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Personeller ID=@Id and PAROLA=@password", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserId;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;


    try
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        result = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        string hata =  ex.Message;
        throw;                      


    }

    return result;

}

public void personelGetbyInformation(ComboBox cb)
{
    cb.Items.Clear();
    bool result = false;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(gnl.conString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Personeller ", con);



    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) ;
        {
            con.Open();
        }

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        cPersoneller p = new cPersoneller();
        p._PersonelId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]);
        p._PersonelGorevId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["GOREVID"]);
        p._PersonelAd = Convert.ToString(dr["AD"]);
        p._PersonelSoyad = Convert.ToString(dr["SOYAD"]);
        p._PersonelParola = Convert.ToString(dr["PAROLA"]);
        p._PersonelKullanıcıAdı = Convert.ToString(dr["KULLANICIADI"]);
        p._PersonelDurum = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["DURUM"]);
        cb.Items.Add(p);
    }
    dr.Close();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Screenshots are not so helpful.  A SqlException means an error was returned by SQL.  In this case, incorrect syntax in your SQL query.  Looks like a missing "where".  Flagging to close, as it's pretty much a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to filter with your `cmd` SQLCommand.  However, you left out the keyword `WHERE`, hence the incorrect syntax error.  It should be something like:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Personeller WHERE ID=@Id and PAROLA=@password", con)
```